# JSONArrays with android

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have a program that can parse a JSONArray but only if the jsonarray has jsonobject in it, like this for example:

```
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}]
```

I am trying to parse a jsonarray that is like this:

```
"messages":["This is a demo message.  Enjoy!","Another demonstration message stored in JSON format.","JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation (I think)","hello"]
```

So what I'm wondering is how I would convert the code I have now to be able to parse this kind of json array.  Here is my current code that parses the jsonarray:

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray(/*"actors"*/"weather");


                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("id"));


                    actorsList.add(actor);

                }
```

If you need to see more of my code just ask and I will be happy to provide it. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to me not JSON compliant, if you check in this website you will notice that: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
if (status == 200)
    {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("messages");
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
        {
            String message = jarray.getString(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate this so much!

Comment: I hate to bug you anymore but would you know how to update this? Would I use like a refresh button or something?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. What you want to update exactly and where ?

Comment: Like say a new item was added to the json array how would I just hit a refresh button or something on the app and the new item would be added to my list.

Comment: You should refresh the adapter : adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I do though here is my code for that:
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) { 
dialog.cancel(); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
if (result == false) 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

}
Do you think you could just elaborate a little more?